# Ruby on Rails session expire date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, expired-cookies

I have following line in my application which let default cookie expire date 20 minutes.

```
Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_rails-omniauth_session', expire_after: 20.minutes
```

Bu I want to set specific expire date for some reasons. I have tried following  lines but they couldn't make it.

```
request.session_options[:expire_after] = 2.years
ActionController::Base.session_options[:expire_after] = 2.years
```

How can set custom expire date ?

Ang suggestions,

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to set expiration period for sessions through all controllers in your application, simply add the following option to your `config/intializers/session_store.rb` file:

```
:expire_after => 60.minutes
```

If you need to set different expiration time in different controllers or actions, use the following code in action or some `before_filter`:

```
request.session_options = request.session_options.dup
request.session_options[:expire_after] = 5.minutes
request.session_options.freeze
```

> Duplication of the hash is needed only because it is already frozen at that point

[Source](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base#693-session-expiration)